# Why $\alpha_1B^{r-1}f_1 + \dots + \alpha_{p_1}B^{r-1}f_{p_1}=0$ is equivalent to $\alpha_1 f_1 + \dots+\alpha_{p_1}f_{p_1}\in H_{r-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Shilov's Linear Algebra, here:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I don't understand why $\alpha_1B^{r-1}f_1 + \dots + \alpha_{p_1}B^{r-1}f_{p_1}=0$ is equivalent to $\alpha_1 f_1 + \dots+\alpha_{p_1}f_{p_1}\in H_{r-1}$. I figured out the following:

- As $g\neq0$, then not all $a_i$ are equal to zero.
- $B^{r-1}f_i\neq 0$ because the height of $f_i$ is $r$, not $r-1$.
- The previous items seems to imply that the $B^{r-1}f_i$ are linearly dependent, since they equal zero.

Now I'm stuck trying to figure out the last bit of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{p_1}\alpha_i B^{r-1}f_i = B^{r-1}\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{p_1}\alpha_if_i\right)}_{=:x} = 0$$

So, $B^{r-1}x = 0$. The assumption was $0 \neq g = Bx \in H_{r-2}$, which means by the very definition of $H_{r-1}$ that $x \in H_{r-1}$.

This in turn is a contradiction to the choice of $f_1, \ldots , f_{p_1}$ as linearly independent over $H_{r-1}$.

Comment: Oh, damn. It was much easier than I thought.